# Array montlhy reporting but not from 1st of month

Tags: php

I have a large array of booking dates and amount, like so :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2014-04-04
        [total] => 30.00
    )

[1] => Array  
    (
        [date] => 2014-04-05 
        [total] => 47.00
    )

[9998] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2014-08-21
        [total] => 52.00
    ) 
    ... ++ a lot of dates associated to numbers.
```

and process it to get monthly reports :

```
$months = array();
foreach($myarray as $k=>$v) {
    list($y,$m) = explode("-",$v['date']);
    $months[$y."-".$m][] = $v['total'];
}
```

which gives me a nice array :

```
Array
(
    [2014-04] => Array    <-- Every amount made in April
        (
            [0] => 30.00
            [1] => 47.00
            [2] => 47.00
            ...
        )

    [2014-05] => Array     <-- Every amount made in May
        (
            [0] => 68.00
            [1] => 42.00
            ....
        )...
```

However I'm trying to find a way the same thing **but starting from a specific day**, say 5 for example, in order to get (dates labelled for clarity):

```
Array
(
    [from January 5 to February 4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30.00
            [1] => 47.00
            [2] => 47.00
        )

    [from February 5 to March 4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30.00
            [1] => 47.00
            [2] => 47.00
        )...
```

So every amount made each month, but starting from the 5th of each month.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with your `$months` array. Could you explain? Also, where do the value `68.00` come from? Is that present in your original array as well? Might help if you post the `print_r()` output of your original array and the expected result so we could understand what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry numbers are dummy. First array is a bunch of day dates+amount. $months array displays for each month the amounts made this month. Expected result is same thing but 5th of the month would be the starting point, and 4th of the next month the ending point.

Comment: OK. Did you read my entire comment?

Comment: I don't understand what you miss. All arrays are printed, imagine the same with 100's of values for the original print.

Comment: Where is the original data coming from - a database? If that is the case then you could use a query to get, and group, this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. I hate saying should, but I don't have the data to test with. Let me know if anything's wrong:

```
$months = array();

foreach($months as $k => $v) {
    list($y, $m, $d) = explode("-", $v['date']);

    if($d < 5) {
        if($m == 1) {
            $y--;
            $m = 12;
        } else {
            $m--;
        }
    }

    $months[$y . "-" . $m][] = $v['total'];
}
```